# Duration of minutes not working correctly in Java/Android

Tags: java, android, duration

I am trying to display a rest time value in hours and minutes to my UI on an application I am finishing up.. I made use of another StackOverflow forum to figure this out and so far it is working okay, the time is displaying, but I think the maths is wrong somewhere..

I have two TextViews, one which displays active time in minutes, and another which displays rest time in hours and minutes (as the rest time will normally be a significantly longer period). The rest time is essentially 24hrs minus the active time.

So far, I have converted my stored active time string to an Int, subtracted that from the minute value for 24 hours (1440 minutes), then used the Duration method to convert that value to hours and minutes (hh:MM) which worked fine, the UI showed the correct subtracted value in hh:MM.

My problem is when I tried to split this into parts using a string, where my string is `(restHours + " h" + restMinutes + " minutes")` I get the hours and minutes value for the entire restTimeInt value (for example: 23h 1430minutes).

How can I change this so it displays the correct minutes value (for example: 23hr 40min)?

```
       int activeTimeValue = Integer.parseInt(activityTime); // ex: 10 mins
           int day = 1440;
           int restTimeInt = day - activeTimeValue; // 1430 mins
           Duration d = Duration.ofMinutes(restTimeInt);
           int restHours = (int) d.toHours();
           int restMinutes = (int) d.toMinutes();

       restTimeTV.setText(restHours + " hr" +  restMinutes + " mins");
```

Comment: Java 9 introduced the methods `toHoursPart()` and `toMinutesPart()` (and so for more units of time that are less relevant here). Do you use Java 9 or above? If yes, use `toMinutesPart()` for `restMinutes`, you would have to write `d.toMinutes() % 60` otherwise.

Comment: Perfect, I was wondering that.. I tried to use toHoursPart() and it was flagging unresolvable.. thanks for your help @deHaar

Answer (score 1):

### Duration.minus() and Duration.toMinutesPart()

Now you’re at it, why not go all in on `Duration` and let it handle all math for you? With a little help it can even parse your string of minutes.

```
    String activityTimeStr = "10"; // Minutes
    Duration activityTime = Duration.parse("PT" + activityTimeStr + "M");
    
    Duration restTime = Duration.ofDays(1).minus(activityTime);
    System.out.format("Rest time: %s%n", restTime);
```

Output is:

> Rest time: PT23H50M

So 23 hours 50 minutes, as expected. If you need those numbers, 23 and 50, for example for formatting for the user, as deHaar said, use the `toMinutesPart` method of `Duration`:

```
    int restHours = Math.toIntExact(restTime.toHours());
    int restMinutes = restTime.toMinutesPart();
    System.out.format("Rest time: %d hours %d minutes%n", restHours, restMinutes);
```

> Rest time: 23 hours 50 minutes